# The meaning of "going over" something

Tags: meaning, verbs, prepositions

I'm fond of old especially folk songs, but as a foreigner I often have troubles interpreting some phrases. Here is one from [Wayfaring stranger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wayfaring_Stranger_(song)):

*I'm going there to see my father

I'm going there no more to roam

I'm just **a-going over** Jordan

I'm just **a-going over** home*

Does "going over" here mean "going to", i.e. approaching to some goal? I can't find some dictionary article which can prove this - though I've seen some about "go over to smth" with similar sense.

Or can this be some archaic, or dialect-specific (Appalachian?) usage, but not "normal" for contemporary / everyday language?

Thanks in advance for guiding me!

Comment: The otherwise archaic style of *a-going*, *a-walking*, *a-cooking*, indeed *a-verb*, remains in some UK dialects of English. It was regularly used by my Norfolk grandparents, less by my parents' generation. But one can still hear it today.

Comment: It's also common in some rural dialects in the USA. It's certainly nonstandard.

Comment: "Going over Jordan" means dying (and presumably going to heaven).

Comment: Yes, the sense of this chorus (and the song as whole) is clear enough... I'm only curious about this "go over" - especially because while I can understand "going over Jordan" - I can't understand "going over home". That is which puzzles.

Comment: It should be remarked that the entire verse refers to dying:  Going see one's father, no more roaming, crossing over Jordan, and going home are all idioms for dying and going to heaven.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an old form of saying "going to" (also used where today we might just say "going").

Examples of usage:

> "In my part of Brooklyn, we always said we were **going "over New
>   York"** (never, as people in Queens said, "to the City")" ([Robert
>   Snyder, *Transit Talk: New York's Bus and Subway Workers Tell Their
>   Stories*, 1997](https://books.google.com/books?id=q1q4347rF-EC&lpg=PR10&dq=%22going%20over%20New%20York%22&pg=PR10#v=onepage&q=%22going%20over%20New%20York%22&f=false))
>
> "i had to pay $17 to park for a hour inside the garage couldn't find
>   parking on street to much of a hassle to continue **going over
>   Philadelphia**" ([RateMDs review, April 22, 2015](https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/414119/Dr-Vaughan+C.-Graves-Philadelphia-PA.html'))
>
> "A man will be coming over town and he will say, 'You **going over
>   town**, Bob?' Whether I am **going over town** or not I always say
>   yes" ([Northwestern Mutual Life Insurance Company *Field Notes*,
>   1918](https://books.google.com/books?id=gKPnAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22going%20over%20town%22&pg=PP4#v=onepage&q=%22going%20over%20town%22&f=false))
>
> "'Where on earth are you going?' '**Over home**,' said Eunice." ([Lucy
>   Maude Montgomery, *Avonlea Chronicles*, 1912](https://books.google.com/books?id=FMcMlcLitn4C&lpg=PT357&dq=%22going%20over%20home%22%20-jordan&pg=PT357#v=onepage&q=%22going%20over%20home%22%20-jordan&f=false))
>
> "I am **going over home** directly after breakfast to give out meal
>   and corn." ([*Send Me a Pair of Old Boots & Kiss My Little Girls: The
>   Civil War Letters of Richard and Mary Watkins, 1861-1865*, Jeff
>   Toalson, ed.](https://books.google.com/books?id=0izTfPEqpC8C&lpg=PA234&dq=%22going%20over%20home%22%20-jordan&pg=PA234#v=onepage&q=%22going%20over%20home%22%20-jordan&f=false))

Note that the penultimate quote is by a Canadian, and the last was from a set of letters between a Virginia couple, so this usage apparently extended at least all up and down the eastern side of North America. Also, if that internet doctor review is not a typo of some sort, it may still be in current usage among some individuals/in some areas.

As for "going over home" in this particular sense, I believe it is the (not uncommon) practice of equating the afterlife and specifically "heaven" with "home". For comparison:

> "**In Remembrance of W.L. Clifton**. . . . He prayed to see me, his only
>   sister, before he died. I arrived there on Wednesday before he passed
>   away Sunday. He said all was ready, he was only **going over home**."
>   (*People and Things from the Walker County, Alabama Jasper Mountain
>   Eagle (1910 - 1913)*, Robin Sterling, ed.)

Comment: Though the question is a duplicate, this answer contains good references of examples unlike the one there.